# index.php?s= does not load other content

Tags: php

The non-profit I work for is trying to move from our overpriced host to a host that offers free hosting to non-profits. My webpage knowledge is old and limited pretty much to html - no knowledge of PHP. Our current host has a custom interface for users and does not allow us to see the files in the public_html folder or download them.

According to their tech support this is not possible with their platform. I have been able to recreate most of our content on the new host site but could not recreate the index.php file. Using a PHP tutorial I created a new one but it does not load any content except the welcome page and I'm not sure what I have done wrong in the code.

My menu items look like this:

```
<li class="on">
  <a href="http://ourcharity/index.php?s=8077" target="_self"class="on">Welcome</a> 
</li>
```

and my index.php code is:

```
<?php
// create an array with data for title, and meta, for each page
$pgdata = array();
$pgdata['8077'] = array(
  'title'=>'WELCOME',
  'description'=>'',
  'keywords'=>'self-sufficiency'
);
$pgdata['8065'] = array(
  'title'=>'About Us',
  'description'=>'',
  'keywords'=>'self-sufficiency'
);

// set the page name
$pgname = isset($_GET['pg']) ? trim(strip_tags($_GET['pg'])) : '8077';

// get title, and meta data for current /accessed page
$title = $pgdata[$pgname]['title'];
$description = $pgdata[$pgname]['description'];
$keywords = $pgdata[$pgname]['keywords'];

// set header for utf-8 encode
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- begin spin_special_output(head_start) -->

  <style type="text/css">
    .wd_featurebox_icon {
      display: inline;
    }
    .wd_featurebox_icon img {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    div.wd_featurebox_group div.wd_tabs_wrapper {
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
      padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    }
    div.wd_featurebox_group div.wd_featurebox {
      border: none;
      padding: 8px 0 0 0;
    }
    div.wd_featurebox_group li.wd_tab {
      float: none;
      color: #666666;
    }
    div.wd_featurebox_group li.wd_tab-active {
      border: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #000000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    div.wd_featurebox_group li.wd_tab-inactive {
      cursor: auto;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function view_printable() {
      var loc = window.location;
      var sep = (loc.search == "") ? "?" : "&";
      var url = loc.protocol+"//"+loc.host+loc.pathname+loc.search+sep+"printable"+loc.hash;
      window.open(url, "_blank", "");
    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    span.wd_page_tool {display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle;}
    div.wd_page_toolbar td span.wd_page_tool {margin: 2px;}
    div.wd_page_toolbar td {text-align: center;}
    span.wd_page_tool a {display: inline-block; height: 16px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle;}
    span.wd_page_tool a span {display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle;}
  </style>

  <!-- end spin_special_output(head_start) -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
  <!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wdcontent.css" />
  <link rel="image_src" href="images/facebook_logo.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerwrapper" align="center">

  <div id="header">
    <div id="headerleft">
      <div id="headerright">

        <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></div>

        <div id="headerinner">

          <div id="topnav">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.php?s=8088" target="_self">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div id="tagbanner">

            <img src="file.php/70929/banner.jpg" border="0"  />
            <div id="tagline">
              Self-Sufficiency
              <h2></h2><p> </p>         </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="search" align="right">
          <div id="searchform">
            <!-- BEGIN T1 SEARCH -->
            <form method="post" action="index.php?s=8092">
              <input class="input" size="15" name="query" value="" />
              <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
            <!-- END T1 SEARCH -->
          </div>
        </div>

      </div><!-- END HEADERRIGHT -->
    </div><!-- END HEADERWRAPPERINNERLEFT -->
  </div><!-- END HEADER -->

</div><!-- END HEADERWRAPPER -->


<?php echo file_get_contents(''. $pgname. '.htm'); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about using `$_GET['s']` instead of `$_GET['pg']`? (2x on line 16)

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much! I have been going over that code for many hours and did not make that correlation but now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: if u want your data sent to appear within the link , just use GET form type

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET['s']` instead of `$_GET['pg']`. (2x on line 16)